# Replacing more than one elements with replace function

Tags: r, dplyr

In `mtcars$am` I want to replace instances of 0 with zero and instances of 1 with one. This is what I tried:

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
dplyr::select(am) %>%
mutate(am.character = replace(am, am %in% c(0, 1), c("zero", "one"))) %>%
as.data.frame

   am am.character
1   1         zero
2   1          one
3   1         zero
4   0          one
5   0         zero
6   0          one
7   0         zero
8   0          one
9   0         zero
10  0          one
11  0         zero
12  0          one
13  0         zero
14  0          one
15  0         zero
16  0          one
17  0         zero
18  1          one
19  1         zero
20  1          one
21  0         zero
22  0          one
23  0         zero
24  0          one
25  0         zero
26  1          one
27  1         zero
28  1          one
29  1         zero
30  1          one
31  1         zero
32  1          one
```

But all this has done is created a vector of c(zero, one) that is repeated 16 times. How can I replace instances of 0 with zero and instances of 1 with one?

Comment: I'd suggest `factor` or `ifelse` instead of `replace`.

Comment: I thought that myself but hoping to learn how `replace` works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try by `numeric` indexing.

```
 mtcars %>% 
    select(am) %>% 
    mutate(am1= c('zero', 'one')[am+1L])
```

Or using `replace`, but this is not useful when there are multiple elements to replace.  Best would be to use `factor` and specify the `levels/labels`.

```
 mtcars %>%
      select(am) %>%
      mutate(am1= replace(replace(am, !am, 'zero'), am==1, 'one') )
```

Or instead of double `replace`, create a column of `zero` and `replace` the `zero' by`one` based on values of "am"

```
 mtcars %>%
     select(am) %>% 
     mutate(am1= 'zero', am1=replace(am1, am!=0, 'one'))
```

Other option where you can change multiple elements with corresponding replacement element is `mgsub` from `qdap`

```
 library(qdap)
  mtcars %>%
        select(am) %>%
        mutate(am1= mgsub(0:1, c('zero', 'one'), am))
```

#### Update

If you need to use `replace` to change the values in one variable based on the other,

```
mtcars %>% 
       select(am,gear) %>%
       mutate(am= replace(am, gear %in% 4:5, 1000))
```

Comment: So how would I make this code work within `dplyr`: `mtcars$am[mtcars$gear == 4 | mtcars$gear == 5] <- 1000`