# R dplyr: Find a specific value in a column, then replace the adjacent cell in the subsequent columns to the right with that value

Tags: r, dplyr, apply, lapply, sapply

I am trying to create a matrix of site and time-of-event. In my case, once the event has occurred ("1") it is permanent and cannot go back to a "0". Once a cell in a column is a "1" I am trying to populate the adjacent cell in the subsequent columns to the right with a "1" (see bellow example).

```
site <- c('A','B','C','D','E','F','G') #site
time <- c(0,1,4,0,3,2,0) # time in which even occured
event <- c(0,1,1,0,1,1,0) # did a event occur
data <- data.frame(site, time, event)

site.time.matrix <- cast(data, site~time)

# This is the output      # This is the desired output
#site   0  1  2  3  4     #site   0  1  2  3  4
#    A  0 NA NA NA NA     #    A  0  0  0  0  0
#    B NA  1 NA NA NA     #    B  0  1  1  1  1
#    C NA NA NA NA  1     #    C  0  0  0  0  1
#    D  0 NA NA NA NA     #    D  0  0  0  0  0
#    E NA NA NA  1 NA     #    E  0  0  0  1  1
#    F NA NA  1 NA NA     #    F  0  0  1  1  1
#    G  0 NA NA NA NA     #    G  0  0  0  0  0
```

I have found some promising code using dplyr e.g. ([Replacing more than one elements with replace function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250018/replacing-more-than-one-elements-with-replace-function) or [Apply function to each column in a data frame observing each columns existing data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303322/apply-function-to-each-column-in-a-data-frame-observing-each-columns-existing-da)) which replaces values, although I am unsure of how to specify the adjacent cell in subsequent columns argument.

My apologies if this question is unclear, this is my first post on StackOverflow.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was welcome surprise for a first user post to be detailed, reproducible and interesting, +1!

With `na.locf` from `zoo` package you could do:

```
library(reshape) # for cast function
library(zoo)    #for na.locf function short for if NA, last observation carrried forward, ?na.locf

site <- c('A','B','C','D','E','F','G') #site
time <- c(0,1,4,0,3,2,0) # time in which even occured
event <- c(0,1,1,0,1,1,0) # did a event occur
data <- data.frame(site, time, event)

site.time.matrix <- reshape::cast(data, site~time)

site.time.matrix.fill <- site.time.matrix


# Transpose the matrix excluding first column, carry forward last observation and 
# transpose again to return to original matrix structure

site.time.matrix.fill[,-1] <- t(na.locf(t(site.time.matrix.fill[,-1])))

site.time.matrix.fill[is.na( site.time.matrix.fill)] <- 0

site.time.matrix.fill

#  site 0 1 2 3 4
#1    A 0 0 0 0 0
#2    B 0 1 1 1 1
#3    C 0 0 0 0 1
#4    D 0 0 0 0 0
#5    E 0 0 0 1 1
#6    F 0 0 1 1 1
#7    G 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Thank's Osssan, I have never heard of the 'zoo' package, this is exactly what I needed. These are all really great answers, I love seeing all the different ways you can do the same thing :)

Answer (score 2):

A `base R` approach using `apply`.

Basically, for every row we are trying to find any element that has 1 in it and assigning 0 to every element in left of it and 1 for every element to the right.

```
t(apply(site.time.matrix, 1, function(x) {
       temp = if(any(x == 1, na.rm = T)) which(x==1)-1 else length(x)
       x[temp:length(x)] <- 1
       x[0:temp] <- 0
       x
}))


#  0 1 2 3 4
#A 0 0 0 0 0
#B 0 1 1 1 1
#C 0 0 0 0 1
#D 0 0 0 0 0
#E 0 0 0 1 1
#F 0 0 1 1 1
#G 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Ronak. I love seeing all the different ways you can do the same thing. I don't have much experience using the apply function, it's something I am hoping to improve on so thank you for helping me with this :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a second base R method (excluding the reshaping). This uses `apply` and `cummax` (cumulative maximum). If only one event occurs for each site, then replacing `cummax` with `cumsum` would return the same result.

```
# reshape the data
temp <- cast(data, site~time)

# construct matrix of 0s and 1s
myMat <- as.matrix(temp[-1])
myMat[is.na(myMat)] <- 0

# expand 1s to the right when they appear
myMat <- t(apply(myMat, 1, cummax))

# add row and column names
dimnames(myMat) <- list(levels(temp$site), seq_len(ncol(myMat))-1)
```

This returns

```
myMat
  0 1 2 3 4
A 0 0 0 0 0
B 0 1 1 1 1
C 0 0 0 0 1
D 0 0 0 0 0
E 0 0 0 1 1
F 0 0 1 1 1
G 0 0 0 0 0
```

---

*Note:*
The reshaping (with `cast`) can also be performed with the base R `reshape` function, but you have to also re-order the variables afterward. For example,

```
# reshape data
temp <- reshape(data, direction="wide", idvar="site")
# reorder variables
temp <- temp[c("site", sort(names(temp)[-1]))]
```

would produce the expected data frame.

```
  site event.0 event.1 event.2 event.3 event.4
1    A       0      NA      NA      NA      NA
2    B      NA       1      NA      NA      NA
3    C      NA      NA      NA      NA       1
4    D       0      NA      NA      NA      NA
5    E      NA      NA      NA       1      NA
6    F      NA      NA       1      NA      NA
7    G       0      NA      NA      NA      NA
```

Comment: @RonakShah  Thanks. I didn't check the results of `reshape` closely enough.

Comment: I love seeing all the different ways you can do the same thing. Thank you for your answer, I look forward to going over all the different types of code today :)